# How to set a mysql bit datype in Laravel's Eloquent? (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a single action to deactivate a user's resource. The action uses a bit value to activate/deactivate the resource but I was surprised that I couldn't set the bit value as I expected. The value is always set to "1", the default value when the resource is created.

```
   public function deactivate(Request $request)

        {

           $resourceId= $request->get('resourceId');

           $resource= \App\Resource::find($resourceId);

           //I've tried the two statements below separetely

           $resource->active= false; //didn't work

           $resource->active= 0;   //didn't work

            //I performed the test below with another column and it worked
            //so the problem isn't my model.

            $resource->anotherProperty = 10;



            $resource->save();
     }
```

even though I don't think the problem is my model, I'm using the database first approach and it is possible that the problem is the model I created.

```
class Resource extends Model
 {



 protected $table = 'resource';
  protected $primaryKey = 'resource_id';

protected $fillable = array( 'announcer_id', 'announcer_type', 'data',  'active');

   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $connection = 'custom_connection';
}
```

updated some minutes after

```
CREATE TABLE `resource` (
 `resource_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `announcer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `announcer_type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `active` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`resource_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=583 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: show table schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I found that MySQL has a boolean data type which is stored as tinyint(1).

I've altered my table

```
alter table resource modify column active boolean  not null;
```

now on my controller

```
$resource->active= false; //works
```